# HighCharts Pie chart gets box around selected slices

Tags: c#, highcharts, webview2

When rendering my HighChart I sometimes get a blue box around one of the slices. This seems to represent the selected slice. If I use the keyboard arrows the box moves to the other slices.
This is how it looks when it renders (sometimes)

[image: Chrome selected]

And then if this happens I can then use the arrow key to change which slice has the box around it like below

[image: Edge slice selected]

I don't see any reference to this in the documentation for HighCharts or any settings to turn this off.
This also only seems to happen when rendering inside of Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 control but I can't be certain. It does not let me cycle through all elements on the control. Once Opera has been selected the next time I hit the right arrow Chrome is selected again so I don't think it's the browser cycling through DOM elements.

Does anyone have any advice on this?

Comment: It looks like something related to the accessibility - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/accessibility/accessibility-module Do you have some config in your app which could trigger the point select?

Comment: I couldn't find anything that should be triggering it but you are right. I took out the reference to the accessibility.js file and it no longer happens. Thanks a lot! If you want to put it as an answer I'll be happy to accept it

Comment: I added the answer to your issue. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments - it seems that the issue was related to the accessibility module - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/accessibility/accessibility-module